# Elasticsearch querying nested objects returning no results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have created Elasticsearch index and one of the nested field has mapping as following.

```
"groups": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
             "type": "text"
        },
        "value": {
             "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

On details about ES version, its 5.0 and I am using official python client [elasticsearch-py](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io) on client side. I want to query this nested field based on its **value**.

Lets say there is another field called **name** which is a **text** type field. I want to find all name starting with **A** and falling under group specified.

Some sample data,

Groups - HR(name=HR, value=hr), Marketing(name=Marketing, value=marketing)
Names  - Andrew, Alpha, Barry, John

Andrew and Alpha belong to group HR.

Based on this I tried a query

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{
                'match_phrase_prefix': {
                    'title': 'A'
                }
            }]
        },
        'nested': {
            'path': 'groups',
            'query': {
                'bool': {
                    'must': [{
                        'match': {
                            'groups.value': 'hr'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this query I referred ES docs but this query does not return anything. It would be great if someone can point out what is wrong with this query or mapping itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you simply need to move the `nested` query inside the `bool/must` query:

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
              {
                'match_phrase_prefix': {
                    'title': 'A'
                }
              },
              {
                'nested': {
                   'path': 'groups',
                   'query': {
                     'bool': {
                       'must': [{
                          'match': {
                            'groups.value': 'hr'
                          }
                        }]
                     }
                   }
                }
              }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would I need to update my mapping to get the desired result?

Comment: It worked. Thanks mate!! Answer is accepted but SO is stopping me right now! So will do it when allowed to.

Comment: No your mapping is fine, just the query was malformed